# How to paste a link to a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, paste

All of the variables are defined correctly. This works till it gets to the final statement shown and then it says

> "Paste method of Worksheet class failed".

```vb
Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet
For Each cell In TargetSheet.Columns(1).Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then FirstRow = cell.Row: Exit For
Next cell
LastRow = FirstRow + 6

Sheets(ClientName).Range("A3:Q9").Copy

With Sheets("4 Policies")
    .Activate
    .Range("A" & FirstRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```vb
Set TargetSheet = ActiveSheet
For Each cell In TargetSheet.Columns(1).Cells
  If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then FirstRow = cell.Row: Exit For
Next cell
LastRow = FirstRow + 6

Sheets("4 Policies").Range("A" & FirstRow).Resize(7, 17).Formula = "=" & ClientName & "!A3"
```

If you trying to find the cell below the last used one in column A, your code becomes

```vb
FirstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheets("4 Policies").Range("A" & FirstRow).Resize(7, 17).Formula = "=" & ClientName & "!A3"
```

or, if the active sheet is "4 Policies"

```vb
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(7, 17).Formula = "=" & ClientName & "!A3"
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot.